# super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs), reports an error TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, superclass

I have a python file. I could run it with Python2.7 without any problems but can not run it correctly with Python3.6. The Python file is

```
__all__ = ['ParallelWrapShotNull', 'ParallelWrapShot']

class ParallelWrapShotBase(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError('ParallelWrapShotBase.__init__ should never be called.')

class ParallelWrapShotNull(ParallelWrapShotBase):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.comm = None
    self.use_parallel = False

    self.size = 1
    self.rank = 0

class ParallelWrapShot(ParallelWrapShotBase):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

    return super(ParallelWrapShot, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    # return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)



    def __init__(self, comm=None, *args, **kwargs):

        if comm is None:
            self.comm = 1
        else:
            self.comm = 2

        self.use_parallel = True
        self.size = 3
        self.rank = 4



if __name__ == '__main__':

    y = ParallelWrapShotNull()
    z = ParallelWrapShot('foo')
```

The error message that I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_exp.py", line 45, in <module>
    z = ParallelWrapShot('foo')
  File "test_exp.py", line 23, in __new__
    return super(ParallelWrapShot, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I think there must be something changed in Python3.6 from Python 2.7. Can anyone help me?